# Distribute GWT module as JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, module

I have the following requirement:

> Produce a GWT module in such a way that it can be used/included in a GWT app *without* recompiling it (so plug and play). This plug and play module would contain a widget and a some random classes. The GWT apps that use this module should be able to extend some functionality from the module.

It seems to me that the obvious solution would be to simply compile the GWT module to JS, then distribute this JS, and use JSNI to link to it.

I was wondering if there is some sort of standard solution for this.

I would also be interested to know your thoughts on how to ensure browser compatibility (i.e. how to hook into GWT's bootstrap process, so that we load the corresponding JS file, for the current browser).

Comment: I hadn't realized that GWT is written using Java (THEN compiled down to JavaScript), so I had mistakenly removed the [java] tag. Mea culpa!

Comment: So you want to make a widget without supplying the user of the widget the source?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to put it. But I think it is more accurate to say that I want to distribute the module without the need to recompile in the host app.

Comment: Right - compiling GWT is pretty slow - that makes sense from that point of view.

Comment: That's not the reason we're trying to do this. I'd explain the reason, but I don't think it matters, because I don't have an option anyway.

Comment: i wrote once javascript script which was calling functions from gwt module, you can achieve that by externalizing gwt functions, which to be honest looks more like nasty hack rather than right way. But it was  slow, loading time of my gwt module was couple times higher. Other thing what you could try, is do pretty compile, and then you should have human readable name of functions, so you could try to do somthing with this, but is it right way to go, i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a long story short, you cannot directly re-use GWT methods if you don't have the Java source. (This is what I call the "Compile time source dependency" of GWT.) So you're already on the right track: You'll have to go via JavaScript.

The project [GWT Exporter](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) makes it a lot easier to export GWT methods to JavaScript. It also makes sure, that your methods are not optimized away by the GWT compiler (which it does, if you never call a method from your code).

Comment: Thanks, I was also contemplating this direction. However, I need to ask about browser compatibility. If I use GWT Exporter, I'd think I will end up with one JS per supported browser. In my client app, that uses such module, I'd have to modify maybe the gwt linker to load only the JS for the current browser. Do you know if/how this can be made ?

Comment: Actually, this should be done just like with any other GWT app: You include the "*.nocache.js" file in your page, and the GWT code (the correct permutation, including the exported JS functions) will be loaded. At the end of your `onModuleLoad` you can start any other scripts, see the part which is marked as "IMPORTANT" on https://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/wiki/GettingStarted